# JWT token appears to be correct but response received is 401

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to use the [JWT Bearer Grant Type](https://www.docebo.com/knowledge-base/authentication-api-ssp-app-grant-types/#post-simple-toc-heading-6) to connect to Docebo API and am running into an issue:

With the code below I receive the following response (even though my $token appears to be correct when validating at https://jwt.io):

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => Unauthorized [message] => Array ( [0] => Your request was made with invalid credentials. ) [code] => 0 [status] => 401 )
```

Here is the code use to generate the $token, and that error ^

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function base64url_encode($data) {
return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

$key = 'example_public_key';

$headers = ['alg'=>'RS256','typ'=>'JWT'];
$headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));

$today = time();
$tomorrow = time() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$payload = [
  'iss' => 'example_client_id',
  'sub' => 'example_user',
  'aud' => 'example.docebosaas.com',  
  'iat' => $today,
  'exp' => $tomorrow
];

$payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key,true);
$signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);

$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";

$curl = curl_init();
$curl_data =  array(
  'token' => $token
); 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,  
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $curl_data, 
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.docebosaas.com/manage/v1/user'
)); 
$resp = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

$json_obj = json_decode($resp);
print_r($json_obj);
```

**UPDATE:**

Per the comment below, I have now added the appropriate headers in and am no longer receiving a 401.   However, changing the CURL call to the following has a new error:

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => invalid_grant [error_description] => JWT failed signature verification )
```

Here is the code for the updated CURL call:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_data =  array(
 'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
 'scope' => 'api',
 'assertion' => $token
); 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,  
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $curl_data, 
 CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.docebosaas.com/oauth2/token'
)); 
$resp = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

$json_obj = json_decode($resp);
print_r($json_obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl example does not include headers that I would expect such as:

```
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
scope=api
assertion=YOUR_SIGNED_JWT
```

Also you may want to instead call the endpoint `https://<yoursubdomain.docebosaas.com>/oauth2/token` to convert your Signed JWT into a normal bearer token. Then you can use the standard Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

[API General Information](https://www.docebo.com/knowledge-base/schema-endpoints-parameters/)

Comment: Hi John -Thanks for calling that out.  Now that I have added those headers, and changed the endpoint I am receiving this error: **stdClass Object ( [error] => invalid_grant [error_description] => JWT failed signature verification )** 

I have updated my original post with the new code that I am using for the curl call.

Comment: The error message means that your signing did not work which could be as simple as not using the correct part of the keypair. You code mentions `public` where normally you would use the `private` keypair for signing. The `public` keypair is used to verify the signature.

Comment: You can generate a public key from the private key, but you cannot generate a private key from a public key. A private key actually contains the two numbers that make up the public key. The public key is missing everything else that makes up the private key.